# Checking DB for Duplicate Data (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms

I'm try to allow a user to add a category (to the database). However, I don't want there to be duplicate categories.

This is what I have so far:

```
using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO category_table AS e (Category) VALUES(@cat) WHERE e.Category != @cat;", sqlconnection))
 {
     //code here to add category to DB
 }
```

However, I get the error:

> "SqlException Unhandled: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

Comment: Look up SQL Constraints

Comment: its the `as e` that sql server is complaining about.  But I agree with @walther, just make it an unique column.

Comment: @paqogomez Can't. Because Category is a `varchar` column.

Comment: Any column can be unique, it doesn't have to be int at all! You just have to limit the number of characters in it. For instance MSSQL has a 900 byte limit on index entries.

Answer (score 2):

Simply mark the column as `Unique`. Don't do the work of DB in C#.

Comment: And what about Subcategories? I have common subcategories between categories.

Comment: @John You didn't ask about subcategories in your question. Don't expand the scope of your question.

Comment: @mason You didn't ask if Categories was an `int` or `varchar`. You can't make it `unique` if its `varchar`.

Comment: @John You're directing your comment to the wrong person.

Comment: @John, you can if you limit number of characters. Like I've said in the comment, MSSQL for instance has a 900 byte limit on index entries, but it's possible for sure. If you want to enforce uniqueness on a larger column, you're probably doing it wrong anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First your insert syntax is wrong. It should be

```
INSERT INTO category_table (Category)  values(@cat)
```

Also remove the where condition. The syntax for insert is wrong.

So it would be like

```
using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO category_table (Category)  values(@cat)", sqlconnection))
 {
     //code here to add category to DB
 }
```

Secondly you need to make the column as `unique` for which you dont want duplication.

Comment: You can't make a `varchar` column `UNIQUE`.

Comment: @John:- You can definitely make it, the command is `ALTER  TABLE  category_table WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_category_table_category UNIQUE (Category)`

Comment: That is negative. I'm using SQL Management Studio, and it will not allow me to make that column `UNIQUE`.

Comment: @John:- Did you try to that query? Its strange if that is not allowing. D let me know the error message which you get!

Comment: @John:- Alternatively you can try to create unique index on that column like this: `CREATE  UNIQUE INDEX IXU_Category ON category_table(category)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your sql.

`INSERT INTO category_table AS e (Category) VALUES(@cat) WHERE e.Category != @cat;`

Inserts don't have a WHERE clause. Further, you can't alias the table you are inserting to.

If you want to only insert into the database conditionally, you need to use a `SELECT` to look and see if there's an existing Category of the same type and only insert if it does not exist, or set the column to be unique via a constraint.